# javascirpt bookmark enable all disabled buttons on page and textbox

Tags: javascript

I want to add javascript 1 line of code to bookmark and click enable all buttons on-page.
removing the disable attr in HTML.

```
  javascript:

  (function(){
$(':input[type="button"]').prop('disabled', false);

  })()
```

or this

```
javascript:Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('textbox1')).forEach(function(v){v.removeAttribute("disabled");});
```

they need to be modified, the innerhtml class or button id may be different so it is better to use some sort of loop and just remove all (disabled) attrr